# Cómo corregir el reemplazo de comodines en este ejercicio en c++?

Tags: c++

> Un texto de n líneas tiene ciertos caracteres que se consideran
> comodines. Hay dos comodines, el `#` y el `?` El primero indica que se
> ha de sustituir por la fecha actual, en formato `día (nn) de mes (nombre) año (aaaa)`, por ejemplo `21 de abril 2001`.
>
> El otro comodín indica que se debe reemplazar por un nombre. Escribir
> un programa que lea las líneas del texto y cree un array de cadenas,
> cada elemento referencia a una cadena que es el resultado de realizar
> las sustituciones indicadas. La fecha y el nombre se ha de obtener del
> flujo de entrada.

y mi codigo es este:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void pointer();
int main()
{
    pointer();  
}
void pointer ()
{
    
    time_t timme;
    time (&timme);
    string days;
    string text;
    
    struct tm * Mytime = localtime(&timme);
    
    cout<<"Ingrese el texto: "<<endl;
    cin>>text;
    
    system ("cls");
    
    cout<<"Su texto: "<<endl<<"\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        cout<<text[i];
    }
    
    if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 2)
    {
        days = "Marzo";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 1)
    {
        days = "Febrero";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 0)
    {
        days = "Enero";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 3)
    {
        days = "Abril";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 4)
    {
        days = "Mayo";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 5)
    {
        days = "Junio";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 6)
    {
        days = "Julio";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 7)
    {
        days = "Agosto";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 8)
    {
        days = "Septiembre";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 9)
    {
        days = "Octuber";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 10)
    {
        days = "Noviembre";
    }
    else if (Mytime -> tm_mon == 11)
    {
        days = "Diciembre";
    }
    
    cout<<"\n"<<"EL texto modificado: "<<"\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == 35)
        {
            cout<<Mytime -> tm_mday<<" de "<<days<<" del "<<Mytime -> tm_year + 1900;
        }
    }
    
}
```

pero al momento de imprimir, sustituye toda la cadena por el comodin

Comment: ¿Por qué llamas a una variable days que lo que alberga es el nombre del mes? Es mejor que crees un array llamado mes que contenga el nombre de todos los meses, con eso simplificas el código y quitas todos los if usados para obtener el nombre del mes. Y luego para reemplazar echa un vistazo a string.replace Y en tu código no estás sustituyendo nada, sólo muestras una cadena si encuentra en el texto el carácter #

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez quién esta pidiendo que le hagan nada? Así no se tratan los usuarios nuevos, sobre todo los que traen su código, su problema y su resultado esperado. La pregunta es válida! (por si acaso, un repaso al [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) no sobra...

Comment: mira el titulo original: `solicito por favor su ayuda para resolver este ejercicio en c++`

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez mira el contenido. Por si te distrae mucho, ya le ayudé al **usuario nuevo** a poner un título acorde a su pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias enserio, no conocia la funcion replace

Comment: @AntonioS.F. llamé a la variable days, porque se suponía que iba a ser para los días de la semana pero no había leído el ejercicio, no sabía que al entrar al bucle no sabía que la condición se comportara de esa manera gracias por el feedback

Comment: Cuando veas que el código se repite mucho ahí hay posibilidad de simplificar lo que redunda en un código más limpio que te hace ver el problema de otra forma. Has probado a buscar string.replace para lograr tu propósito de sustituir # por la cadena de fecha.

Comment: @GustavoReyes Recuerda que, si una respuesta soluciona tu problema, puedes marcarla como aceptada para que todos sepan en el futuro que esa es la solución. Si te sirvió de alguna forma, la puedes votar positiva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código es simple, e implica varios puntos de importancia a tener en cuenta:

```
void pointer ()
{
  time_t timme;
  time (&timme);
  string text;
  string mes[12] = {"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril",
                    "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto",
                    "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};

  struct tm *Mytime = localtime (&timme);

  cout << "Ingrese el texto: ";
  // Esto te permitirá leer tambien los espacios
  getline(cin, text);

  system ("cls");

  cout << "Su texto: " << endl;
  cout << text <<endl;
  
  cout << "\n" << "EL texto modificado: " << "\n";

  // Construyo el texto que se usa en el reemplazo
  string mi_Fecha = to_string(Mytime->tm_mday) + " de " +
                    mes[Mytime->tm_mon] + " de " +
                    to_string(Mytime->tm_year + 1900);

  // Localizamos la posición del carácter #
  size_t pos = text.find("#");
  // Si lo encontramos sustituimos por la cadena
  if (pos != -1) 
    text.replace(pos, 1, mi_Fecha);
  
  // Mostramos el texto modificado.
  cout << text;
}
```

El hecho de utilizar un array con los meses simplifica bastante el código y lo hace más legible. Piensa también que la forma de nombrar las variables es muy importante en tanto hace el código más comprensible.

Mira que también usamos

```
// Esto te permitirá leer también los espacios
getline(cin, text);
```

Lo que nos permite introducir una frase entera ya que ***cin>>text;*** la va a truncar en el primer espacio que encuentre.

Y por ultimo la parte más importante que es

```
// Localizamos la posición del carácter #
size_t pos = text.find("#");
// Si lo encontramos sustituimos por la cadena
if (pos != -1) 
  text.replace(pos, 1, mi_Fecha);
```

En esa porción de código averiguamos en qué posición se encuentra nuestro carácter y usaremos dicha posición para reemplazar ahí nuestra  cadena.

Sé que habrás hecho ya tus averiguaciones y podrás comparar con el código que te aporto.

Comment: enserio muchas gracias

Comment: ¿me podría explicar por que pos tiene que ser distinto de -1?

Comment: Con ese condicional lo que preguntamos es si ha encontrado el comodín. Sólo si lo encuentra procedemos a la sustitución dado que sabemos la posición. Si lo encuentra va a devolver la posición que será 0, 1, 2, ... según donde esté.